# Java Equivalent Media Queries

Tags: java, android, media

What would be the equivalent of the following media queries in Java?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 359px)" href="css/320_533.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 599px)" href="css/360_640.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 799px)" href="css/600_1024.css">        
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 800px)" href="css/800_1280.css">
```

Comment: can you explain what that piece of code is doing?

Comment: I guess it selects a different style sheet basing upon the screen resolution. Which is **not needed** in *Android* app development.

Comment: Hi, the goal is to detect the corresponding css-html file to load in the webview, according to the viewport dimensions. That is, if the resolution is between 360px and 599px, then it loads the 360.html and 360.css files. Thank you.

Comment: Android doesn't use stylesheets for its UI.

Comment: The above code snippet is for the css part, I would like to find its java equivalent to load the html content for the webview.

Comment: It's a **bad idea** (also known as **ant-pattern**) to make web-based UIs on Android.

Comment: Using the below code snippet returns 480px as the width, while it's real value is 320px.   WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
  Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
  DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  display.getMetrics(metrics);
  andWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
  andHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

Comment: Again, it's an anti-pattern to think in px. And no, Android development is **not pixel-perfect friendly**.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. I used to use javascript "window.innerWidth" function before to detect the width and it was working fine. But after android system webview update it started to return bigger width values. I changed it to "screen.width" and now it works fine.
Thank you. 
Best regards.

Comment: Actually, the following javascript code returns correct result for resolutions 320px - the previous code returned 480px for 320px device width: if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 359px)').matches) {  //call java function to load the related html file.else if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 599px)').matches) {... Thank you.

Comment: As I already told you, `It's a bad idea (also known as ant-pattern) to make web-based UIs on Android` **and** `it's an anti-pattern to think in px. And no, Android development is not pixel-perfect friendly.`